# A neighborhood of a connected subset is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a **connected** topological space and $A$ a connected subset of $X$. Do we have that a neighborhood of $A$ in $X$ must be connected ? For example consider the sphere $ X=S^2$ and take $A$ a connected part of the open upper hemisphere, is the sphere minus the equator circle a neighborhood of the part $A$ in $X$ ?

Comment: Is your question "is every neighborhood of $A$ in $X$ connected?" or "does there always exist some neighborhood of $A$ in $X$ which is connected?" The answer to the former is false, by considering any situation where $X$ is disconnected.

Comment: The first one and by assuming that $A$ is connected and $X$ is also connected.

Comment: In your sphere example, yes, that is a neighbourhood of $A$ that is not connected.

Comment: Is $U=[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ disconnected? i mean $[0,1)$ and $\{2\}$ are disjoint but $\{2\}$ is not open. My definition of a disconnected set is a set that is a union of disjoint open sets.

Comment: NO i think it is open because $\{2\}=U\cap (1.5,3)$ hence $\{2\}$ is open in $U$ which is endowed with subspace topology of $\mathbb R$. And similarly $[0,1)=U\cap (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Connected and Local Connectedness do not imply each other. Here are a few examples (by @Ross Millikian),

$\Bbb R$ is connected and locally connected.

$[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ is locally connected but not connected

The topologist's sine curve is connected but not locally connected.

$\Bbb Q$ is neither